# Call to undefined method laravel 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, eloquent-relationship

I'm new in laravel,
I'm trying to get an avatar for the user who is logged in, but i keep getting a error.

**Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::getAvatar() (View: D:\PI\Project\crud\resources\views\layouts\includes\navbar.blade.php)**

here's my view

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><img src="{{auth()->user()->mahasiswa()->getAvatar()}}"
    class="img-circle" alt="Avatar">
    <span>{{auth()->user()->name}}</span> <i class="icon-submenu lnr lnr-chevron-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

        <li><a href="/admin/{{$mhs->id}}/profile"><i class="lnr lnr-user"></i> <span>My Profile</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="lnr lnr-envelope"></i> <span>Message</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="lnr lnr-cog"></i> <span>Settings</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="/logout"><i class="lnr lnr-exit"></i> <span>Logout</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

it's my controller

```
public function profile($id)
{
    $mhs = Mahasiswa::find($id);
    return view('admin.profile', ['mhs' => $mhs]);
}
```

Mahasiswa model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\User;

class Mahasiswa extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'mahasiswa';
    protected $fillable = ['nama', 'npm', 'kelas', 'fakultas', 'program_studi', 'email', 'avatar', 'document', 'user_id'];
public function getAvatar()
{
    if(!$this->avatar){
        return asset('images/default.png');
    }

    return asset('images/'.$this->avatar);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class)->withDefault(['avatar' => 'default.png']);
    }
}
```

User model

```
public function mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Mahasiswa::class);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello you are calling relationship, try it like this

```
auth()->user()->mahasiswa->getAvatar()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is here:

```
auth()->user()->mahasiswa()->getAvatar()
```

You are calling your relationship as a method (i.e. `mahasiswa()` ) rather than a property (`mahasiswa`). This will return a query builder instance rather than the model you were looking for.

Try this:

```
auth()->user()->mahasiswa->getAvatar()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are returning a QueryBuilder Object if you use function notation on your relationship. So `auth()->user()->mahasiswa()` returns query builder. Then when you do `->getAvatar()` it is trying to call the function on the query builder, and it is obviously not there.

Laravel will do some "magic" for your methods that return relationships. If you call `auth()->user()->mahasiswa` it will return the result of the relationship and return you a `Mahasiswa` object. So what you should be calling is:

```
auth()->user()->mahasiswa->getAvatar()
```